# How to modify the Saloon or Guzzle libraries in Laravel globally?

Tags: php, laravel, request, guzzle

I have a project that uses the Saloon library for creating APIs for different external providers. It is really helpful. This library uses Guzzle internally, so I would like to know how to modify the Saloon o Guzzle globally because I would like that when doing external requests, and those requests return a 500 status error message, it triggers an alert in sentry

App\Exceptions\Handler

```
$this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
   if (app()->bound('sentry') { 
     app('sentry')->captureException($e);
   }
});
```

that alert only triggers when a reportable error happens, I was thinking that I could modify my apis like this:

```
  $response = $request->send();
  if ($response->status() >= 500){
     report(new Exception('there was an error....'));
  }
```

The problem is I have more than 20 services integrated, and every service has many methods that make requests, so I would need to modify every request, and new services are integrated often. I was thinking maybe extending the Guzzle or Saloon library to catch the 500 error. I am not quite sure what to do.

Comment: Did you try guzzle handlers and middlewares, for example you can use retry middleware if status is 500 do what ever you want. here is a link for documentation https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html

Comment: you are right my friend, I am trying that solution

Comment: it is working, now the issue is how to test it, I am going to ask other question

Comment: For the testing, I would say the best solution is https://pestphp.com/ if you write some tests for your httpClient. 

Or try to trigger 500 responses manually, I think nobody knows that better than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use guzzle handlers and middleware, for example, you can use retry middleware if the status is 500 do whatever you want.

here is a link for documentation: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html